# Airflow 2.0.0: MySQL Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

The airflow scheduler is consistently dying. Is it a bug in airflow? Or do I need to bump up my timeout in MySQL?

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

MySQL current setup:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
 
__________________________|____
|innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50 |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I will recommend updating to 2.0.1 -- I added bunch of fixes that will help

Comment: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log

Comment: In that case try Airflow 2.0.1, there are fixes for MySql 5.7 and Mariadb

Comment: I will give it a try and see if it resolves this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to run `airflow db upgrade` or `airflow db init` after upgrading from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1?

Comment: Yup, run `airflow db upgrade` after upgrading to 2.0.1